# Browse vmdk file in Windows

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmdk

I'm running OS X Maverick on my vmware, but since yesterdays windows update and some weird drive repair that windows did automatically I can't boot the machine any more it's stuck at Apple progress bar at 50% , after some time at 50% Vmware just closes machine. I have some source codes of my app on that machine. How can I browse machine data in windows? I tried Vmware mapping but it doesn't work, it never adds a new drive.

Comment: Could you please be clear which operating system is your Host OS and which one is your Guest operating system?  It seems to me that your Host is running Windows (which version?) and the Guest is Mac OSX running on the VMware Workstation Hypervisor.  Please could you confirm how your OS's are layered and which versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer is a mix of both, I used [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to browse .vmdk file, after that I extracted .hfsx file and opened it with [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/). With HFSExplorer I was able to extract source codes and other documents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already say that you cannot map the file to a drive, I perceive that you tried to map automatically.
There are two options:

1. Try to mount using `vmware-mount.exe` from the [VMware Disk Mount Utility](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=46&downloadGroup=WKST-550-DISK-MOUNT-UTL) (you may need to disable driver signature verification to install the driver)

> To mount a vmdk file (saved at C:\temp) in read-only mode use the
>   following command:
>
> `vmware-mount.exe X: C:\Temp\TestVM.vmdk`
>
> Now you have a read-only access to the vmdk file using your windows
>   explorer (navigate to driveletter X:).
>
> If the vmdk file contains more than one partition you can use the
>   parameter /v:x to mount the other volumes:
>
> `vmware-mount.exe /v:2 X: C:\Temp\TestVM.vmdk`

2. I think that vmdks can be opened using 7-Zip

Source: http://www.running-system.com/how-to-mount-a-vmdk-file-under-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't.

You can not natively browse an OSX partion on Windows.  OS X uses the HFS+ file system, which windows does not understand.

There might be a work around solution using a utility `HFS Explorer` or `Paragon HFS+ for Windows` and using the `vmware-mount.exe X: C:\Temp\TestVM.vmdk` but this may well not work.

Finally (and this is your best option) you could spin up a Linux VM, install the `hfsprogs` package, attach your Mac OSX vmdk file, and then mount your OSX partition.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os